# Xcode 4 Version Editor: ignore whitespace

Tags: xcode, version-control, xcode4, version-editor

Does anyone know how to get the version editor in Xcode 4 to ignore whitespace?

Update:

I sent in a bug report. The bug report was closed as a duplicate. The state of the original bug report is closed. In the latest version of Xcode (4.3) I still cannot find a way to remove whitespace checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent in a bug report. The bug report was closed as a duplicate. The state of the original bug report is closed. In the latest version of Xcode (4.3) I still cannot find a way to remove whitespace checking.

Answer (score 24):

Solution:

Right click in the gutter between both editors and select "Hide Whitespaces".

[image]

I've also tried modifying git config (git config add core.whitespace) but that didn't work.

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: Heh – I thought this no longer worked in Xcode 9.2. It does, but: I only get the menu if I right-click _anywhere **except** for the gutter between the panes_. Right click on either pane, and the option to "hide white space" will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

The [Xcode manual page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html) referencing the Visual Editor doesn't mention any option regarding whitespace.

However, check if you have the "[Comparison and Differencing Options](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeSourceManagement/30-Source_Control/source_control.html)" in Xcode 4, which should allow you to specify what you want to ignore.

[image: Comparison and Differencing Options]

Comment: This image is from the old Xcode. Xcode 4 preference panel does not have these options

Comment: @rp90 that is what I feared. That would be a shame, then, if that option wasn't available at all.