# Xcode 9 – ignore white space changes in file compare

Tags: xcode, diff, whitespace

Xcode has an integrated graphical diff view in the "Version Editor" which is extremely handy. There's some explanation of it [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/153084/use-git-source-control-xcode-9).

I'm wondering if or how it can be made to ignore white space changes in Xcode 9 (or, in future, the latest version). For Xcode 4 [there is a reasonable solution to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9011363/2547229), but this doesn't work for Xcode 9.

Comment: There is still the option of hiding the whitespace, even in Xcode 9.

Comment: @the4kman Oh, great – where is that? If I do as described in the link, I don't get an option to hide white space.

Comment: Strange, [it does appear for me as described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkhuv.png).

Comment: I worked this out :-) I get the menu if I click anywhere except for the gutter in the middle! So, that's brilliant, thanks.

Comment: It's 2024 and we have Xcode 15, but still can't ignore whitespaces